# How can I use Google's spreadsheet API to retrieve the date and time a spreadsheet is created?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api-python-client

How can I retrieve the time a spreadsheet was created using the Google API Client?

The spreadsheet properties of `service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=sheet_id).execute()` do not seem to contain it.

Comment: You should use Files.get of drive api

Comment: @TheMaster I think that your comment is the answer to this question. So, how about posting it as an answer?

Comment: @Tanaike Added. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google sheets API cannot retrieve metadata information about a file. Use [Files:get](https://googleapis.github.io/googlye-api-python-client/docs/dyn/drive_v3.files.html#get) of the Google Drive API instead:

```
service.files().get(fileId="sheet_id",fields="createdTime").execute()
```

Also, you would need authorization using one of the [these scopes](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get#auth). At a minimum, metadata scope

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata
```

is needed.